# Doing which things purifies a person and causes him to get rid of all (or some) of his past sins?

Tags: sin

It is believed that by taking bath in Ganga river a person get rid of all his past sins.
Which other things are also capable of making a person pure and making him free from his past sins.

Comment: Observing Ekadashi, bathing on any waterbody during eclipses, performing sandhyavandana, purascharana of the Gayatri mantra - these are some rites known to dispel sins of both this life & past lives.

Comment: Yes the above statement really obsolves the sins but with all of the above there should be resolve from the spiritual aspirant not to commit the same sins again after doing praischitta. otherwise no matter bathing and fasting have no impact.

Comment: Hari nama japa and sankirtana.....